# How to plot numbers read from socket in Java?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, plot, graph

I am working with a robot with a distance sensor mounted to a servo. I have written code that sends data over the wifi module that looks like this "10 .4". This data corresponds to "distance(cm) servo angle". I have this code to communicate with the robots wifi module (robot is connected to computers wifi).

```
Socket robotOutput = new Socket(192.168.1.1, 228);
BufferedReader data = new BufferedReader(robotOutput.getInputStream());
```

Now `data`should be handling the input stream, and what I want to do is take the input distance and servo angle and plot it as the data comes to produce a "radar" plot. This is where I get stuck. Assuming that my code works below to pull the two numbers, how would I plot these in real time on my computer? Should I add all input data into an array and then re-plot all values as soon as I get a new value?

```
while(1)
{
    ArrayList<Double> degree = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> radius = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double x, y;
    String line = data.readLine();
    String[] strs = line.trim().split("\\s+");
    radius.add(Double.parseDouble(strs[0]);
    degree.add(Double.parseDouble(strs[1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < radius.size(); i++)
    {
        x = radius.get(i) * cos(degree.get(i));
        y = radius.get(i) * sin(degree.get(i));
        plot(x,y); ??? Not really sure where to go here 
}
```

Comment: What is `sock`? Is that supposed to be `robotOutput`? --- If so, then what do you think `robotOutput.getInputStream().read()` does? If you think it reads **and discards** one byte from the stream, then you're right. But which byte? Well, the next bytes after what has already been read into the **buffer** in `BufferedReader`. If you wrapper an `InputStream` with a `BufferedReader` or `BufferedInputStream`, *stop* using the underlying stream directly. Actually, that advice goes for *all* wrappers, not just the buffered ones.

Comment: @Andreas I changed that bit of code, I was confused about the `robotOutput.getInputStream().read()`, but I basically want it to run forever. I'm not sure if data.readLine() functions the same way, where it waits until their is input data, but assuming it does I think that while loop would work? My biggest issue right now is plotting in real time, as I will be able to figure out the data input when I get access to a robot.

Comment: You tagged `server` too, so does that mean there is a client where the plot is displayed? How does server tell client about the update? --- Basically, answer to your question depends on what a "plot" is, i.e. where it is stored, and how/when it is displayed. Standalone app, e.g. Swing? If so, why the `server` tag? Web server? Other kind of server?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, that was a bit misleading on my part. The robots "acts" as a server when connecting through java (we normally connect to it through Putty). I want the plot to be displayed wherever the java code is running (I connect to the robot and data is plotted on my screen when I run the code).

Comment: So...... Swing?

Comment: @Andreas Yep, Swing.

Comment: Then tag it....